# lxml.html5parser: not working for arabic/persian html5s

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, lxml

I'm using lxml's html5parser
it's okay with ascii characters, but if I download an html file which has persian and russian characters inside it, this error will appear:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 418: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this is the response text: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23552349/

and this is my code (as you see I have only removed all non valid xml characters):

```
f = requests.post('http://www.example.com/getHtml.php?', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
resp = f.text
if resp == "":
    return []
resp = encode("utf-8")
resp = ''.join(c for c in resp if valid_xml_char_ordinal(c))
doc = html5parser.fragment_fromstring(resp.encode("utf-8"), guess_charset=False, create_parent='div')
```

- if I remove the line: resp = encode("utf-8") this error will appear:

  ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

Comment: for lazy morons with a mouse cursor ready on -1: this is not a duplicate :))

Comment: i don't really understand why you encode the response to utf-8. What happens if you just feed the response as unicode to fragment_fromstring ?

Comment: @StephaneMartin if you don't you'll get the useChardet error !

Comment: Yes. Looks like a bug in lxml. lxml just "wraps" the html5lib library. the "useChardet" only exists in lxml, but it's improperly passed to html5lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face some strange inconsistencies when using html5parser directly (`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'useChardet'` and things like that).

If you already installed lxml, working with the BeautifulSoup wrapper is a joy.

First install BeautifulSoup (`pip install beautifulsoup4`). Then:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# (initialize headers, cookies and data)

f = requests.post('http://www.example.com/getHtml.php?', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
resp = f.text
if not resp:
    return []
doc = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')
```

Then you can use the BeautifulSoup clean API to manipulate the HTML tree. Under the hood it still uses lxml for parsing.

Ref for BeautifulSoup API: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = ''.join(c for c in resp if valid_xml_char_ordinal(c))
```

This attempt to filter out the bad characters doesn't work because the control characters in your input are actually encoded as numeric character references, not raw characters:

```
<td class="artistFlux">السيف النشيد الدولة الإسلامية التي من شأن&#16</td>
```

Specifically `&#16` (obscured here by the right-to-left text). Control characters like U+0010 (16) are invalid in HTML5 [even as character references](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references).

It would be best if you can to fix the upstream script that produced this cruft, but if you have to remove bum character references like this from input you could do another filter to remove a regex like `&#(3[01]|2[0-9]|1[124-9]|[0-8]])(?=[^0-9])`.

BTW you don't need to mess around with encoding and decoding normally. You can read the original bytes of the response from `f.content` and feed that directly to html5parser, to avoid decoding the reponse to `text` and then re-encoding it to bytes. You probably also want `fragments_fromstring` plural, as you have two top-level elements in your input.